# SQLPLUS not getting credentials from ewallet.p12 file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-wallet

Followed https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E78494_01/aip/pdf/1411/html/ig/aip-ig-apx_wallet.htm guide and created ewallet.p12 (also generates cwallet.sso), sqlnet.ora, and tnsnames.ora:

```
PS C:\Users\myname\Oracle> echo $env:ORACLE_HOME
C:\app\oracle\product\19.0.0\client_1
PS C:\Users\myname\Oracle> echo $env:TNS_ADMIN
C:\Users\myname\Oracle\my_admin
```

Then tested my credentials, and tnsnames.ora successfully:

```
sqlplus user/password@tns_alias
```

However, removing user and password from above (expecting to get them from ewallet.p12 file) errors out:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jul xxxxxxxxx
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
Enter user-name:
```

and then entering username and password when prompted, gives me tns adapter error:

```
Enter user-name: user
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Following is sqlnet.ora content:

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=TRUE

WALLET_LOCATION = 
    (SOURCE = 
    (METHOD=FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = C:\Users\myname\Oracle\my_wallet)))

TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=16
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT = client.trc
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT=%USERPROFILE%\ORACLE
```

and the content of wallet folder:

```
PS P:\> ls C:\Users\myname\Oracle\my_wallet\


    Directory: C:\Users\myname\Oracle\my_wallet


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       30/07/2020   7:59 PM           2509 cwallet.sso
-a----       30/07/2020   7:39 PM              0 cwallet.sso.lck
-a----       30/07/2020   7:59 PM           2464 ewallet.p12
-a----       30/07/2020   7:39 PM              0 ewallet.p12.lck
```

This seems to be very simple but not sure what I've missed?

Comment: can you provide the content of the directory where the wallet files are ?

Comment: did you configure your sqlnet.ora file ?

Comment: Hi Roberto,
Updated my question with sqlnet.ora content and wallet folder.

Comment: Hi Kiarash, I post an answer. I believe you must follow it and let me know below in the answer any problem you might find

Comment: simply use sqlplus user/@tns_name and let me know what error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a WALLET for authentication using a password store it is a good advice to include two additional files ( `sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora` ) different to the ones you use normally for connections with passwords.

Copy the `tnsnames.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` to the same wallet directory and follow this steps:

3.Edit the `sqlnet.ora` to look like this

```
WALLET_LOCATION =
   (SOURCE =
     (METHOD = FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
       (DIRECTORY =  C:\Users\myname\Oracle\my_wallet )
     )
    )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_VERSION = 0
```

3.Your new `tnsnames.ora` must contain the entries for the wallet ( either service_name or sid )

```
MY_EXAMPLE=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server  )(PORT = port ))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = databasesid)))
```

4.SET the TNS_ADMIN to the location of the new sqlnet and tnsnames files

```
SET TNS_ADMIN=C:\Users\myname\Oracle\my_wallet
```

5.The directory with all files should look like ( In my case I use Linux )

```
-rw-------. 1 orafil finance    0 Feb  6 16:30 ewallet.p12.lck
-rw-------. 1 orafil finance    0 Feb  6 16:30 cwallet.sso.lck
-rw-rw-r--. 1 orafil finance  235 Feb 18 10:26 sqlnet.ora
-rw-rw-r--. 1 orafil finance  454 May 14 11:35 tnsnames.ora
-rw-------. 1 orafil finance 2872 May 14 14:26 ewallet.p12
-rw-------. 1 orafil finance 2917 May 14 14:26 cwallet.sso
```

Then connect

```
sqlplus user/@MY_EXAMPLE
```

Comment: any news here ??

Comment: Great! Thanks Roberto.
The missing piece was "SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE".
The "sqlplus user/@TNS1" command you shared throws syntax error so user should be removed.
Also "SSL_VERSION = 0" followed "SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE" that needs to be corrected. 
Wish could give you more points. :)

Comment: no problem. I was using TNS1 as the alias I put in my example; anyway I edited the answer to fix the typos ;)